# Trying to get property 'status' of non-object

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want create role admin and member in login multi user laravel

My Code in Middleware CheckStatus (chek role)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\User;


class CekStatus
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = \App\User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if ($user->status == 'admin') {
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        } elseif ($user->status == 'member') {
            return redirect('member/dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When I process login , I've get error `Trying to get property 'status' of non-object`

Comment: Just `print_r($user);die;` and see if you are getting anything. You have to check if the `$user` exists or not.

Comment: as it says `user` is not object, probably array, try `$user['status']` or print it

Comment: Try dd(Auth::user()); and see if the status field is present or not. The auth will provide you the data of current logged in user.

Comment: `first()` can return `null`, which means it did not find a record by that 'email'

Answer (score 0):

Please check the users table, is there any user which not belong to any role. Assign the rule to each user then it will work perfectly.

You can check the relation using tinker

```
php artisan tinker
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly checking status first check user exists or not afterwards check for status as first() will return object.